# Python formatter Black throws flake8 error multiline SQL string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, flake8

I'm trying to incorporate the [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) formatter for Python code as part of my pre-commit workflow. I also use flake8 as a linter. There seems to be a formatting discrepancy between flake8 and Black when it comes to multi-line SQL strings.

Consider a simple file called **dbtools.py**:

```
import sqlite3

conn= sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor= conn.cursor()

def getResults(targetNumber):
    cursor.execute(
        """
        with participants_join as (select chat_id, participant from participants where participant != %(targetNumber)s),
        message_count as (select chat_id, sms_body from messages),
        contact_names as (select rowid, phone_number, name, alias, source, notes from aliases),
    >  >distinct_chats as (select distinct chat_id from participants)

        select p.chat_id, pa.participant, count(mc.sms_body) as count, c.name as name, c.alias as alias, c.source as source, c.notes as notes, c.rowid as aliasID from distinct_chats p
        left join participants_join pa on pa.chat_id = p.chat_id
        left join message_count mc on mc.chat_id = p.chat_id
        left join contact_names c on c.phone_number = pa.participant
        group by p.chat_id
    """,
        {"targetNumber": targetNumber},
    )
```

Black fails to replace the tabs at the line beginning `distinct_chats` but does replaces tabs with spaces everywhere else. That's obviously making flake8 throw `E101` and `W191` errors about mixing tabs and spaces and having tabs in the code. Can someone explain this behavior? Why would Black allow mixing of tabs and spaces and throw no errors or warnings?

Comment: black's not perfect?  I'd suggest reporting a bug though it seems odd that black changed *anything* inside a string literal -- it really shouldn't do that since it changes the meaning of the string

Comment: @AnthonySottile changing tabs to spaces inside a string literal change the meaning of it?

Comment: yep!  `"""\t"""`  is a different string than `"""    """`